# How to change code in "Pie Chart" in HighCharts

Tags: javascript, jsp, spring-mvc, highcharts, graph-visualization

I Used to Spring MVC. This is my Java Service

```
    @Override
public ArrayList<SampleVO1> getAvgPetalBySpecies3() {
    ArrayList<SampleVO1> irisList = new ArrayList<SampleVO1>();
    try {
        REXP result = rEngine.eval("(ming <- tapply(iris$Petal.Length, iris$Species, mean))");
        REXP result1 = rEngine.eval("names(ming)");

        SampleVO1 sample1 = new SampleVO1();
        sample1.setName(result1.asStringArray());
        sample1.setY(result.asDoubleArray());
        irisList.add(sample1);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage());
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    return irisList;
}
```

Oh! This is my VO

```
    private String[] name;
    private double[] y;
```

And This is my Controller

```
    @RequestMapping("/analytics/iris3")
public String getAvgPetalbySpecies3(Model model) {
    ArrayList<SampleVO1> irisList = analyticsService.getAvgPetalBySpecies3();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String irisData = gson.toJson(irisList);
    model.addAttribute("irisData2", irisData);

    return "analytics/visual";
}
```

At Last, This my JSP

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
Highcharts.chart('pie', {
    chart: {
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBorderWidth: null,
        plotShadow: false,
        type: 'pie'
    },
    title: {
        text: ''
    },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
            },
            showInLegend: true
        }
    },

    series: 
           <%= request.getAttribute("irisData2") %>,

});
});
</script>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiL1U.jpg)

lol I saw White space...
and I checked my sourceCode!

```
    series: 
           [{"name":["setosa","versicolor","virginica"],"y":[1.462,4.26,5.552]}],
```

I thought I receive not bad to iris data! but my highCharts didn't like that...
How I fixed My code...?

Comment: Your series data is formatted incorrectly. Please look at [series<pie>.data](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series%3Cpie%3E.data) to see how to properly format the data.

Comment: yeah... I know I read the highchart...... but How to change my service.java...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You currently have the following code to add values to your data.

```
SampleVO1 sample1 = new SampleVO1();
sample1.setName(result1.asStringArray());
sample1.setY(result.asDoubleArray());
irisList.add(sample1);
```

Where you set name = `[]` of strings, and Y = `[]´` of Doubles.

This gives you `[[name, name, name],[y,y,y]]`

Instead you should either join or loop through the number of elements in your lists as follows:

```
for(int i = 1; i < result.length(); i = i + 1) {
    SampleVO1 sample1 = new SampleVO1();
    sample1.setName(result1[i].asStringArray());
    sample1.setY(result[i].asDoubleArray());
    irisList.add(sample1);
}
```

Which will give you a list like `[[name, y], [name, y], [name, y]]`.
I am sure there is much better ways to add two arrays together in java though.

Regardless, in the end you should en up with a JSON formatted list such as:

```
[{name: 'setosa', y: 1.462}, {name: 'versicolor', y: 4.26}]
```

Comment: WHOA! I succeeded my pie-chart! I changed my code in your advice and then I changed my Value Object and Some edit my jsp. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Highcharts Series takes a JSON Object. You need to convert <%= request.getAttribute("irisData2") %> to a json object as below.

```
 var irisData2_string = '<%= request.getAttribute("irisData2") %>';
 var obj = JSON.parse(irisData2_string);
```

Comment: Inspect the element to view the exact error in console

Answer (score 0):

Thanks EveryOne!

I write my full code for pie-chart in highCharts!
First, I show My ValueObject!

```
public class SampleVO1 {

private String name;
private double y;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String resultList1) {
    this.name = resultList1;
}
public double getY() {
    return y;
}
public void setY(double resultList) {
    this.y = resultList;
}
}
```

Second, My service!

```
@Service
public class AnalyticsService implements IAnalyticsService {

private static final Logger logger = 
LoggerFactory.getLogger(AnalyticsService.class);

@Autowired
Rengine rEngine;

...
    @Override
public ArrayList<SampleVO1> getAvgPetalBySpecies3() {
    ArrayList<SampleVO1> irisList = new ArrayList<SampleVO1>();
    try {
        REXP result = rEngine.eval("(ming <- tapply(iris$Petal.Length, iris$Species, mean))");
        REXP result1 = rEngine.eval("names(ming)");

        double resultList[] = result.asDoubleArray();
        String resultList1[] = result1.asStringArray();

        for(int i=0; i<resultList.length; i++) {
            SampleVO1 sample1 = new SampleVO1();
            sample1.setName(resultList1[i]);
            sample1.setY(resultList[i]);
            irisList.add(sample1);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage());
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    return irisList;
}
```

Third, my Controller~

```
@Controller
public class AnalyticsController {

@Autowired
IAnalyticsService analyticsService;

@Autowired
IUploadFileService uploadFileService;

...
    @RequestMapping("/analytics/iris3")
public String getAvgPetalbySpecies3(Model model) {
    ArrayList<SampleVO1> irisList = 
analyticsService.getAvgPetalBySpecies3();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String irisData = gson.toJson(irisList);
    model.addAttribute("irisData2", irisData);

    return "analytics/visual";
}
```

At last, My visualizing jsp!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
Highcharts.chart('pie', {
    chart: {
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBorderWidth: null,
        plotShadow: false,
        type: 'pie'
    },

    title: {
        text: 'pie is ApplePie'
    },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
            },
            showInLegend: true
        }
    },
    series: [{name: 'Species',
            colorByPoint : true,
            data :<%= request.getAttribute("irisData2") %>
    }]
});
});
</script>
```

I hope these codes help you editing your highCharts!